# Approximate convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

$\psi:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. $f_n\in H^k(\Omega)$, $f_n$ is continuous and $k>\frac{m}{2}$. It is given that

$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|f_n(x)-\psi(x)\right| = \epsilon\forall x\in D,$$ $D$ is a countable dense subset of $\Omega$.

It is known that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum_{|\alpha|=k}\|D^{\alpha}f_n \|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} = O(1)$$ As $k>\frac{m}{2}$ what the above equation says is the sequence $\{f_n\}$ does not converge to a discontinuous function.

Can we say that there exists a $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|f_n(x)-\psi(x)\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} = \delta(\epsilon)  $$

Comment: What is $\epsilon$ ? Does it depends on $x$ ?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @LL3.14 : $\epsilon$ is a constant.

Comment: @supinf : In the case of $\epsilon = 0$, the result holds due to Sobolev embedding theorem and Morrey's inequality. In this case $\delta = 0$.

Comment: Don't you have that the functions are uniformly $\alpha$-Holder continuous for some $\alpha > 0$?  Then you could pick a finite set of points in $D$ so that every point in $\Omega$ is within distance $\eta>0$ of one of these finite points, where $\eta$ is sufficiently small.  Then you find $N$ such that for $n \ge N$, $|f_n(x) - \psi(x)| < 2 \epsilon$.  Then you use the uniform $\alpha$-Holder nature of the $f_n$ to get the bound you want.  And $\delta(\epsilon) = 3 \epsilon$ if you choose $\eta$ small enough.

Comment: Or is there some problem if the boundary of $\Omega$ is weird?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith : The boundary I am i9nterested in is Lipschitz. Will look into your hint. You may sketch a rough answer so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith : How to use the condition that the norm of the k-gradient is bounded. (the second condition in the problem). How to connect this with Holder continuity of the functions.

Comment: $k>m/2$, so you can use Sobolev embedding to Holder spaces @RajeshDachiraju

Comment: Oh got it. Morrey's inequality gives me a bound on Holder norm in terms of norm of gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Morrey's inequality, you have that the functions are uniformly $\alpha$-Holder continuous for some $\alpha>0$. Then you pick a finite set of points in $D$ so that every point in $\Omega$ is within distance $\eta>0$ of one of these finite points, where $\eta$ is sufficiently small. Then you find $N$ such that for $n≥N$, $|f_n(x)−ψ(x)|<2ϵ$ for all $x$ in that finite set. Then you use the uniform $α$-Holder nature of the $f_n$ to get the bound you want. And $δ(ϵ)=3ϵ$ if you choose $η$ small enough.  (You could actually get $\delta(\epsilon) = \epsilon$ if you push it a little more.)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I am able to prove it.